# Native wrappers for complete webapp

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, native

I have a complete webapp (built with [React](https://reactjs.org/) + [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)), and want to keep developing it in HTML5 only, but wrap it for iOS/Android platform with as little effort as possible (due to limited time/resources) to be able to offer it in Appstore/Google Play.

So no need for any UI features, only the webview wrapping. Is [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/) the best choice, or is there any even easier alternatives? Pros/cons? Does not have to be free.

I would guess it should be possible to wrap a lot of the native features using the equivalent HTML5 javascript APIs, like iOS/Android push notifications when calling the [HTML5 Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API), but native features is a lower priority than being able to easily wrap the webapp for native platforms.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is a product. So I would suggest to stick on with Apache cordova (https://cordova.apache.org/) for now and later pick a product that enables you to run cordova based applications. All you need is one code base that runs with multiple mobile platforms. Cordova does it.

Comment: So then I can just wrap the existing webapp with Cordova? It does not require rewriting the whole base architecture, module tree or webpack build?